# Packer - AWS Windows 2016 SysPrep returns exit code 1

Tags: amazon-web-services, sysprep, windows-server-2016, packer

When attempting to SysPrep an AWS Windows Server 2016 instance using Packer the following error is thrown:

```
Build 'amazon-ebs' errored: Script exited with non-zero exit status: 1. Allowed exit codes are: [0]
```

I'm calling the `SysprepInstance.ps1` script as specified on http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/WindowsGuide/ec2launch.html#ec2launch-sysprep.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Castrohenge's answer set me on the right path, but I preferred to pass the '-NoShutdown' switch to SysprepInstance.ps1 to accomplish the same goal.

```
C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Scripts\SysprepInstance.ps1 -NoShutdown
```

Also keep in mind that features requiring restart can lock up sysprep and will fail to report back to packer. To solve that I simply use the '[restart](https://www.packer.io/docs/provisioners/windows-restart.html)' provisioner in packer before sysprep.

Answer (score 1):

The issue was caused by the fact the `SysprepInstance.ps1` script shutdown the instance, using the following command:

```
# Finally, perform sysprep.
Start-Process -FilePath $sysprepPath -ArgumentList ("/oobe /shutdown /generalize `"/unattend:{0}`"" -f $answerFilePath) -Wait -NoNewWindow
```

I resolved this by modifying the `SysprepInstance.ps1` before running it, as follows:

```
$sysPrepInstanceFile = "C:\ProgramData\Amazon\EC2-Windows\Launch\Scripts\SysprepInstance.ps1"

(Get-Content $sysPrepInstanceFile -Verbose).Replace("/shutdown ", "") | Set-Content $sysPrepInstanceFile -Verbose
```